# [NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm getting this error: `[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array` although I have 75 items in my database. Why is it showing me this error? I'm trying to get items from my database but it tells me index 0.

```
+(NSMutableArray *)GetAttitudeItems
{
    NSArray *arrDocPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *strDestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ItemsAndCategory.sqlite",[arrDocPath objectAtIndex:0]];


//sqlite3 *sqlite;

NSMutableArray *arrItemsList;
if(sqlite3_open([strDestPath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK)
{

    const char *strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE CategoryName='ATTITUDE' ORDER BY RANDOM()";
    NSLog(@"The value is %s",strQuery);
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    //char *err;

    arrItemsList  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, strQuery , -1,&stmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) 
        {

            NSString *StrCatename = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
            NSString *StrItemName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0)];

            Itemslist *itemlist = [[Itemslist alloc]init];
            itemlist.CategoryValue = StrCatename;
            itemlist.ItemValue =StrItemName;
            [arrItemsList addObject:itemlist];

        }

    }

    if (stmt!=nil)
    {
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }
}



sqlite3_close(database);

return arrItemsList;
```

}

Comment: Check arrAlert is empty or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are confident that your DB calls should return data, I would make sure that at least one of your if () else () statements is actually getting hit. Otherwise, your array is empty given that you initialized it above:

`NSMutableArray *arrAlert = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

A simple way to check for yourself would be to add an `else` statement at the bottom of your `if` `else` chain, and assert something there (i.e. at least print something, for starters.)